# How to fix "The specified type member 'UserId' is not supported in LINQ to Entities" in ApplicationUserManager

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, ado.net, usermanager

I'm currently working on an older MVC 5 website that originally was using a code-first generated database with Entity Framework. It has since been converted to db-first, refactored, and I'm now in the process of removing the old entity c# files and replacing them with ADO.net's entity framework.

The problem I'm currently having is when logging in, I hit the following line in the ApplicationUserManager (which derives from UserManager(TUser, TKey)):

`var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);`

And I get the following error:
"*The specified type member 'UserId' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.*"

Our ApplicationUser entity which mirrors the db table uses the variable 'Id' instead of 'UserId.' I overrode the method in question and it worked but I don't want to do that whenever we need to use the UserManager. So I guess I'm confused, does UserManager require the variable be named, 'UserId?' If not, how can I tell it to use 'Id'?

I don't think I'm missing anything (like accidentally adding a 'UserId' in a LINQ statement somewhere).

Comment: have you played with the attribute `[Column("your db column name here")]`? If I understood correctly what you need is to map your class property to the proper DB column name, right?

Comment: So I'm auto-generating the entity classes using ADO.net entity framework. I don't believe it's recommended to change anything in the class manually. Perhaps I can do it through the edmx somehow?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm doing and it seems to be working so far. In the Create method of ApplicationUserManager, instead of

`var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationUserRole, int, ApplicationLogin, ApplicationRole, ApplicationClaim>(context.Get<AppDbContext>()));`

I created a CustomUserStore that derives from several identity interfaces:

`var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new CustomUserStore(context.Get<AppDbContext>()));`

It starts like this:

```
    public class CustomUserStore : IUserStore<ApplicationUser, int>,
    IUserEmailStore<ApplicationUser, int>,
    IUserRoleStore<ApplicationUser, int>,
    IUserPasswordStore<ApplicationUser, int>,
    IQueryableUserStore<ApplicationUser, int>,
    IUserLockoutStore<ApplicationUser, int>,
    IUserLoginStore<ApplicationUser, int>,
    IDisposable
{
    public IQueryable<ApplicationUser> Users => ctx.ApplicationUsers;

    private AppDbContext ctx { get; set; }

    public CustomUserStore(AppDbContext _ctx)
    {
        ctx = _ctx;
    }
```

I then override all the necessary methods. It's not what I originally wanted but for now it'll do.